# Cannot find ocsinventory-agent in $PATH

Tags: command-line, ocs-inventory-ng

I am trying to install OCS Agent on Ubuntu. I installed OcsInventoryServer without any problems. I can also use Ocsreports.

But when I try to unzip the agent and start the installation, I encounter:

```
can not find ocsinventory-agent in $PATH
```

I got a little knowledge about environment variables, how to modify them, etc. I want to modify the variable `$PATH` in the long run, I have been trying to modify this variable in the `.bashrc` file, but inspite of everything absolutely nothing is happening there.

---

<sup>**Editor's note:** This post was originally written in French and was translated to English using online tools. For the original text, refer to [revision #1](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/896411/1).</sup>

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. As this is an english speaking Q&A site, please translate your question into english. This way you also get to have a bigger pool of potential helpers. Thank you.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of the same user's [How to modify $PATH?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/896402/how-to-modify-path)

Comment: Hello, yes, sorry I thought tthat there were french people too :) sorry for the duplication in this case !

Answer (score 1):

Make the path change at the end of the /etc/profile file:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/path/of/ocsagent
```

Comment: Hello, my last line is a "fi". Do I write just below ?

Comment: Yes, place it right under the last line.

Comment: I still have the same mistake : can't find ocsinventory-agent in $PATH

Comment: try reboot (or restart the related service).  Also, double check that you are adding the correct path.  I dont know OCS, but if it's like java, you have to add "/opt/java/bin", not "/opt/java" to the path.  (i.e. add the path to the binary file, not the path to the installation directory...)